# Matlab Curve Fitting without Toolbox

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to find a fitting curve as described below. MATLAB's [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polyfit.html) does not work in my case.
Known parameters: `x` and `y`, and the fitting curve `y_fit = a * (x_fit) .^ n`
(here, n may not be an integer).
I need to find `a` and `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Take the logarithm of both sides and use `polyfit` or just a plain `x = A\b` approach.

y_fit = a*(x_fit).^n

log(y_fit) = log(a) + n*log(x_fit)

If `x_fit` and `y_fit` are column vectors of data:

```
A = [ones(length(x_fit), 1), log(x_fit)];
b = log(y_fit);
x = A\b;
n = x(2)
a = exp(x(1))
```

Comment: I have solved the question by using "fminsearch". I also tried your method, but it didn't give me the right result. thanks any way.